Rigging Blender
I've recently started getting into rigging, and I aim to achieve realistic deformations, inspired by Chris Jones. Right now, all my practice is focused on rigging a hand with realistic deformation. I've also sculpted a hand and added veins, but I'm not entirely satisfied with the result. Unfortunately, there isn't much information available about rigging at this level.
I'm adding morphs and linking them to drivers. I was thinking about this and came to the conclusion that veins probably don't need to be sculpted and rigged. It seems like they should be baked and then extruded onto the texture using a Normal map. Could you advise me on how to realistically represent veins?
Additionally, I’m restricting finger movement using IK: when the finger is extended, it can rotate along the X and Z axes, but when it curls into a fist, I use a driver to limit movement along the X axis. When the IK targets the fist position, only Z-axis movement remains, as I aim for maximum deformation. How often do high-level riggers use this approach
I’m also using a multiresolution modifier to enhance the model’s quality, but I feel like this might not be the right approach as it unnecessarily increases the mesh load. I’m considering optimizing this process right away.
If you have experience in detailing, could you help me figure out the best approach? I’d really appreciate it if you could share your expertise. Thank you!



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Here is some info: https://studio.blender.org/training/realistic-human-research/
